# echo text after curl command on same line

Tags: curl, newlines, http

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(curl -s -I https://google.com|grep Server)" abc
```

returns:

```
abcer: gws
```

and `bash -x` shows:

```
++ grep Server
++ curl -s -I https://google.com
' abco 'Server: gws
 abcer: gws
```

but

```
echo abc "$(curl -s -I https://google.com|grep Server)"`
```

returns

```
abc Server: gws
```

In other words, if I add text AFTER the curl command, it gets mangled, but it's ok if I add it before curl.
What is happening? I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $(curl -s -I https://google.com|grep Server)|cat -A
```

shows that the value returned by curl has a ^M (a carriage return).  When you print out the output of the curl, the carriage return takes the 'cursor' back to the start of the line, where it then prints out the ' abc', overwriting 'Serv'.

In your second attempt, the carriage return has no obvious effect.

Answer (score 5):

The HTTP standard specifies that all header lines, as well as the empty line that marks the end of the headers, must use CRLF (carriage return, line feed) endings. A lot of clients are liberal and accept LF alone, but most servers, including Google, respect the standard.

`curl -I` displays the headers exactly as sent by the server, including the CR characters. As far as a Unix system is concerned, a CR character is part of the line, it's only the LF character that ends the line. Command substitution removes trailing LF characters but doesn't touch CR characters. So, the command substitution `$(curl -s -I https://google.com|grep Server)` returns (in your case) the string `Server: gws␍` (where `␍` is a carriage return), and the command `echo "$(curl -s -I https://google.com|grep Server)" abc` displays a line containing

```
Server: gws␍abc
```

The `␍` character is an instruction to the terminal to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, so the characters `abc` overwrite the first three characters of the line.

This also explains why the trace from `bash -x` is somewhat garbled.

The command `echo abc "$(curl -s -I https://google.com|grep Server)"` displays a line containing

```
Server: gwsabc␍
```

The ␍ character moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, then the linefeed moves the cursor to the beginning of the next line, so the ␍ has no visible effect.

To avoid complications due to CR, strip them from the input.

```
echo "$(curl -s -I https://google.com | tr -d '\r' | grep Server)" abc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to remove carriage return:

```
 echo "$(curl -s -I https://google.com|grep Server)" abc | tr -d "\r"
```

Output:

```
Server: GFE/2.0 abc
```