# Odd characters added to string in command substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a shell script that has the following construct:

```
    ...
server_addr="address"
run_user="user:password"
job_url=$(curl -X POST -u ${run_user} -s -i http://${server_addr}:8080/webportal/rest/v4/repository/users/BIRT/report_problem:jobs | grep Location | grep -o -E '[^ ]+$')
job_state=$(curl -X POST -u ${run_user} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -s -i ${job_url} | grep state |  grep -o -E '[^ ]+$')
```

The first variable `job_url` must evaluate to a URL which is then used in the second command. The issue is with the resulting URL. When I run it from in the terminal directly, I get a normal link:

```
http://address:8080/webportal/rest/v4/jobs/e0356d1c-ce69-489d-8f3c-40ae240cae6d
```

...but, when this is used in a script - it fails. The bash debug mode shows the issue:

```
++ curl -X POST -u user:password -s -i http://address:8080/webportal/rest/v4/repository/users/BIRT/report_problem:jobs
++ grep -o -E '[^ ]+$'
++ grep Location
+ job_url=$'http://address:8080/webportal/rest/v4/jobs/e0356d1c-ce69-489d-8f3c-40ae240cae6d\r'
```

For some reason the URL has the regex symbols: `$'http://address:8080/webportal/rest/v4/jobs/e0356d1c-ce69-489d-8f3c-40ae240cae6d\r'` and this breaks all further script functionality.

What is the reason for this? I have tried changing quoting in cURL, switching between awk and grep and checking the bash options. I'm running `bash-4.1.2-41.el6_8.x86_64` on RHEL 6.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: [echo text after curl command on same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217066/echo-text-after-curl-command-on-same-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like whatever server you are querying is configured to return Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`) instead of the "normal" *nix style `\n`. Unfortunately, unlike `\n`, `\r` aren't stripped from command output when assigning to a variable.
To illustrate:

```
$ var=$(printf 'hello\n')
$ printf  '%s' "$var" | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
$ var=$(printf 'hello\r\n')
$ printf  '%s' "$var" | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \r
0000006
```

As you can see, the `\n` is automatically removed but the `\r` is not. So, if you can't change the configuration of the server, you'll just need to remove the `\r` yourself:

```
job_url=$(curl ... | grep Location | grep -o -E '[^ ]+$' | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation and the example. This worked for me.