# bash string substitution re-arranging string?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, curl

The problem I am facing is concatenating a variable that stores a command is not acting like a string when concatenating it with a regular string. An example of this is:

```
base_url=$(curl -sIL --max-redirs 2 'https://hp.com' | ggrep -Po 'Location: \K(.*)$' | tail -1)
# at the time of writing this post the location is: https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html
test_url="https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html"
echo "${base_url}/subroute"
echo "${test_url}/subroute"
```

This then outputs:

```
/subrouteww8.hp.com/us/en/home.html
https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html/subroute
```

I cannot understand why the output is not identical. I apologize if this has already been asked but I haven't found another question dealing with this problem.

Comment: Possibly related: [echo text after curl command on same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217066/echo-text-after-curl-command-on-same-line)

Comment: This was the solution @steeldriver. I can't believe I forgot to check for return carriages. Thank you!

Comment: You *may* be able to avoid the problem altogether by requesting a write-out of the `redirect_url` directly ex. `curl -sL -w '%{redirect_url}\n' --max-redirs 2 'https://hp.com'`

Answer (score 1):

Running your script with `set -x` enabled and you can see the `curl` command returns output with a carriage return in it:

```
$ ./script.sh
++ curl -sIL --max-redirs 2 https://hp.com
++ ggrep -Po 'Location: \K(.*)$'
++ tail -1
+ base_url=$'https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html\r'
+ test_url=https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html
+ echo $'https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html\r/subroute'
/subrouteww8.hp.com/us/en/home.html
+ echo https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html/subroute
https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html/subroute
```

---

You can use bash parameter expansion to remove it:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_url=$(curl -sIL --max-redirs 2 'https://hp.com' | ggrep -Po 'Location: \K(.*)$' | tail -1)
base_url=${base_url/$'\r'/}
test_url="https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html"
echo "${base_url}/subroute"
echo "${test_url}/subroute"
```