# Weird result when piping text into sed replacement

Tags: linux, sed, gnu

I make a network call (using `curl`), and filter the result (using `grep`) to get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. Then I want to transform it to a JSON hash (so I can use it in `jq`).

I want this transform: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`  --->  `{ "status": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" }`

So I tried: `curl ... | grep ... | sed -E 's/^(HTTP.*)$/{"status":"\1"}/'`
But it gives this strange output: `"}status":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

I also tried saving to file `foo` first: `cat foo | sed -E 's/^(HTTP.*)$/{"status":"\1"}/'`
But it gives the same nonsensical output.

Interestingly, this works: `echo 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' | sed -E 's/^(HTTP.*)$/{"status":"\1"}/'`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Likely the curl output is CRLF-terminated

Comment: @steeldriver Interesting idea, it makes sense as it wraps to the beginning of the line ("CR"). Assuming it is, how can I transform it?

Comment: You can also use `-w` to let `curl` output some information in the format you want right away, e.g. `curl -s -o /dev/null -w '{"status": %{http_code}}\n' http://www.example.com` will give `{"status": 200}`

Comment: How to transform, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Thanks guys you were right - curl is giving me CRLFs. As a quick test I used `awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }'` and it works as expected. I'm not sure if that's the best approach though, crlf<-->lf conversions seem to be tricky! If someone adds a portable/gnu solution I'll close.

Comment: @pLumo Lol I was typing as you commented. Do you reckon my `awk` approach above is safe enough circa 2020? Those answers are ancient and come with warnings (maybe no longer relevant).

Comment: See Gilles' answer on the question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Kusalananda Which question?

Comment: Your question is now marked as a duplicate of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217066/echo-text-after-curl-command-on-same-line

Comment: @Kusalananda Lol needed to do a refresh page ;)

Comment: @Kusalananda That link is reasonably recent and very helpful, thanks!