# Bash scripts misinterprets command after piping grep and sed

Tags: bash

It seems that bash misinterprets the command `shasum` and `tar`. It's a weird problem where something previous in the script is affecting the code.

From the code below,

- `shasum` is executed and presented as: `: asum: monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.15.0.4.tar.bz2`
- `tar` is executed and presented as: `'ar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.15.0.4.tar.bz2`

Hence, both of these commands are failing. What is my mistake here?

*PS. For those of you who wants to try to run the complete code, the public pgp key must be imported in order to verify the hash: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/utils/gpg_keys/binaryfate.asc*

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

filename=$( curl -L --head https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/linux64 2> /dev/null | grep Location: | sed 's:.*/::' )
filename_stripped=$( echo "$filename" | sed 's/\..[^.]*\.tar.bz2/ /g' )
version_repo=$( echo "$filename_stripped" | awk -F"-v" '/x64-v/ { print $2 }' )

echo "" 
echo Current version: $version_current
echo Repo version: $version_repo
echo ""

function update { 
    # Update
    wget -O hashes.txt https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt
    gpg --verify hashes.txt
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo Signature OK
        wget --content-disposition https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/linux64
        curr_shasum=$( shasum -a 256 "$filename" | awk '{ print $1 }' )
        grep "$curr_shasum" hashes.txt 
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo Hash OK
            tar xvf "$filename"
        else
            echo Hash NOT ok
        fi

    else
        echo Signature NOT ok
    fi
}

while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to update?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) update;break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Likely your `$filename` has a carriage return at the end - see [echo text after curl command on same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217066/echo-text-after-curl-command-on-same-line)

Answer (score 0):

[@steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578721/bash-scripts-misinterprets-command-after-piping-grep-and-sed#comment1076953_578721) provided the answer. I had an invisible carriage return in the filename and solved it with:

```
filename_CR=$(curl -L --head https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/linux64 2> /dev/null | grep Location: | sed 's:.*/::')
filename=$(echo $filename_CR | tr -d '\r')
```