# Weird behaviour of string concatenation in Bash

Tags: bash, variable, echo

I have a problem with bash and string concatenation.

Let's say that I have 2 variables:

```
FILENAME=/rust-analyzer-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.gz
URL=$(http --headers https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/releases/latest | grep Location | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}')
```

they both are looking good when `echo`ed:

```
$ echo $URL
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/releases/tag/2022-05-02
$ echo $FILENAME 
/rust-analyzer-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.gz
```

but when I'm trying to concatenate them, I get weird outputs:

```
$ echo $URL$FILENAME 
/rust-analyzer-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.gz/releases/tag/2022-05-02
$ echo "${URL}${FILENAME}" 
/rust-analyzer-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.gz/releases/tag/2022-05-02
```

I'd rather expect `https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/releases/tag/2022-05-02/rust-analyzer-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.gz` as an output.

I haven't worked with bash in a while, but I have googled how to concatenate strings in Bash and it looks that `echo $VAR1$VAR2` or `echo "${VAR1}${VAR2}"` shoud do the trick... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does `$URL` end in a carriage return character?

Comment: @steeldriver 100%

Comment: Looks like it... one sneaky bastard!

Comment: Add `| tr -d '\n'` on end of the subshell in URL=$(...

Comment: It's essentially the same issue as [echo text after curl command on same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217066/echo-text-after-curl-command-on-same-line).

Comment: @MrR they'd want to delete `\r` rather than `\n` I think? Command substitution is going to strip trailing newlines anyhow

Comment: You don't need grep when you're using awk.  `grep Location | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'` would be better written as just `awk '/Location/ {print $2}'`.  I've left out the the `-F ' '`, because it's redundant - from `man awk` (GNU version): *In the special case that FS is a single space, fields are separated by runs of spaces and/or tabs and/or newlines.*  If you want to explicitly exclude tabs + newlines as field sep, use a regex that matches a single space or multiple spaces - e.g. `-F '[ ]' or `-F '[ ]+'`